# How to call unadorned C++ function from C++/CLI

Tags: linker, c++-cli

I've written a C++/CLI function which I can call from Fortran.  It is specified as

```
extern "C"
{
    void __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl someFunct(int val)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This works; it calls managed code, and I can call it from Intel Visual Fortran.  When I dumpbin the DLL, I see that it is exported as _someFunct

I now want to call this function from another C++/CLI DLL.  I've tried the following spec (with and without a leading underscore), but both fail the same way:

```
extern "C" extern __declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl someFunct(int val);
```

The error message I get is this:

```
Error   4   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000A) "extern "C" void __cdecl someFunct(int)" (?someFunct@@$$J0YAXH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall NUnitTesting::Class1::Test(void)" (?Test@Class1@NUnitTesting@@$$FQ$AAMXXZ)
```

It seems the linker expects an adorned name, even though I specify extern "C" in the spec.  How can I force the name to be unadorned?

Comment: It is just the way it looks, you are actually calling a function with C++ name decoration.  It is the **thunk**, code that transitions from managed to unmanaged code execution and then calls someFunct().  The thunk is generated by the linker.  But that did not happen, the linker could not find the definition for someFunct since you forgot to link the import library of the DLL.  So the thunk did not get generated either.  Using [DllImport] is not a real substitute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  My spec has to be preceeded by name of DLL:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

[DllImport("DLL_with_someFunct",CallingConvention=CallingConvention::Cdecl)]
extern "C" extern void __cdecl someFunct(int val);
```